# How to populate Recyclerview with images retrieved from firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

How to populate a Recyclerview with images retrieved from Firebase storage?

I'm trying to use a pattern I learned in one of the courses, but it doesn't seem to apply

Here's the adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter (
    private val onClickListener: OnClickListener) :
    ListAdapter<GiftData, RecyclerViewAdapter.DataViewHolder>(DiffCallback)
    {


        class DataViewHolder(private var binding: GridViewItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
            fun bind(GiftData: GiftData) {
                binding.data = GiftData
                binding.executePendingBindings()
            }
        }

        companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<GiftData>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: GiftData, newItem: GiftData): Boolean {
                return oldItem === newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: GiftData, newItem: GiftData): Boolean {
                return oldItem.imgSrcUrl == newItem.imgSrcUrl
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int
        ): DataViewHolder {
            return DataViewHolder(GridViewItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val data = getItem(position)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onClickListener.onClick(data)
            }
            holder.bind(data)
        }

        fun interface OnClickListener {
            fun onClick(data: GiftData)
        }
}
```

The Binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("giftData")
fun bindGiftRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<GiftData>?) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as RecyclerViewAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data)
}
```

the Recyclerview xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gift_photos_grid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="6dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:giftData="@{viewModel.data}"
            app:spanCount="2"
            tools:itemCount="16"
            tools:listitem="@layout/grid_view_item" />
```

The call to firebase which returns string urls for the images:

```
fun getImagesUrl(callback: (String)-> Unit){
    var url: String
    val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference.child("images")
    storageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
        listResult.items.forEach { result ->
            result.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                url = it.toString()
                callback.invoke(url)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The viewmodel: Here I'm trying to set the value of [Data] a mutablelivedata list of the data class that's holding the images url which then I'm going to load into the view item, but the returned is a list of strings while the required type is a list of the data class holding the url

```
class OverviewViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _status = MutableLiveData<NetworkStatus>()
    val status: LiveData<NetworkStatus>
        get() = _status

    private val _data = MutableLiveData<List<GiftData>>()
    val data: LiveData<List<GiftData>>
        get() = _data

    init {
        getData()
    }

    private fun getData(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _status.value = NetworkStatus.LOADING
            try {
                getImagesUrl {
                    _data.value = listOf(it)
                    _status.value = NetworkStatus.DONE
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("failed", e.toString())
                _data.value = ArrayList()
                _status.value = NetworkStatus.ERROR
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question what I understand is that you need to fetch the image in the recycler view item.
So to this kindly follow the steps below:

```
 // add the dependency of Glide in build.gradle file (app level)
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'    
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

and in the onBindViewHolder you can simply pass the link to the glide to load it in the item's imageView

```
 Glide.with(this)  
     .load(MEDIA_LINK)  
     .into(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW);
```

and further you can also attach listeners to it if you need.

**Feel Free to ask if something is unclear and if it helps you kindly mark it as the correct answer.**

Comment: Sorry to ask. But what about the diffutil callback?  to update the correct items? don't I need to pass it through a data class first?

Comment: The above code is to load the image. and kindly elaborate what you want.

Comment: Look I'm sorry but I'm really new to programming. But from my understanding the pattern I know off, passes the data into a data class in this example [GiftData], so it can apply the DiffUtil call backs to correctly update the recyclerview, and then loads it using a binding adapter and submit list. I don't need to do all that for this task?

Comment: No problem and don't feel sorry we are here to help  and ask freely. and if you don't mind I would like to refer to a channel on youtube EDMTDev you can learn a lot from his Kotlin series. I have also learnt from there.

Comment: Channel noted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And BTW I do development in java, so I can jsut illustrate you the structure but couldn't help you with the code , that's why I thought EDMT's video can help you.

Comment: yeah of course no problems buddy,  your help is appreciated as well as the channel suggestion

Comment: Thanks man, BTW the structure is you can use a viewModel and in that make a function to retrieve data from firebase and in the fragment/ activity you observe that function and inside the result of observer you just pass the data to the adapter and now in adapter you can load Images using glide.

Comment: yeah, I could do that. But then I won't be able to use ListAdapter to calculate the updates correctly...

Comment: The DiffUtil callbacks, are items the same, and are content the same